# AngularJS : ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I m beginer in AngularJS, and i try to do this :

```
<form ng-repeat="prop in tab">
<input ng-model="prop" type="text">    
</form>
{{tab}}
```

With this code inputs values is ok, but when i edit value the reverse binding to "tab" don't work.

How i can simply do this ?

Thanks for yours tips ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see changes in your html document live you either need to move the expression inside the form tag and change it to {{tab.prop}} or outside the tag but also showing the property you are interested in displaying such as {{tab.somePropertyName}}.

Comment: I would like to modify value in a tab (a array) with inputs...
In example {{tab}} show : ["A","B","C"]